# jQuery hide element while preserving its space in page layout

Tags: jquery, html

Is there a way in jQuery where I can hide an element, but not change the DOM when it's hidden? I'm hiding a certain element but when it's hidden, the elements below it move up. I don't want that to happen. I want the space to stay the same, but the element to be shown/hidden at will.

Can I do this?

Comment: how about giving it zero width?

Comment: @mrtsherman: zero width is discouraged: many screen-readers (as used by users who are blind or who have low vision) will still read out content that is 'hidden' in this way, which may confuse them as presumably the content isn't supposed to be available at this point in time. Using css visibility:hidden is the way to go here.

Comment: You can save the height dynamically before fadeIn and fadeOut your elems => see downstairs (I'm using it in a products loop.) $('.or-woo-bt').parent().parent().parent().hover(function() {
        // Preserve space;
        var rightHeight = $(this).height();
        $(this).css('height', rightHeight);
        // Hide;
        $(this).parent().parent().find('a span.family-price').fadeOut();
    }, function() {
        // Show;
        $(this).parent().parent().find('a span.family-price').fadeIn('slow');
    });

Answer (score 307, accepted):

Instead of `hide()`, use:

```
css('visibility','hidden')
```

`hide()` sets the `display` style to `none`, which completely removes the element from the document flow and causes it to not take up space.

`visibility:hidden` keeps the space as it is.

Comment: `css('visibility','visible')`

Comment: or `css('visibility', '')`

Answer (score 42):

Try setting the `visibility` to `hidden`:

```
$("#id").css("visibility", "hidden");
```

Answer (score 20):

`display: none;` will take it out of the content flow so you'll see your other content move into the empty space left behind. (`display: block;` brings it back into the flow pushing everything out of the way.)

`visibility: hidden;` will keep it within the content flow taking up space but simply make it invisible. (`visibility: visible;` will reveal it again.)

You'll want to use `visibility` if you want your content flow to remain unchanged.

Answer (score 15):

in another answer it is noted that jQuery's `fadeTo` does not set `display:none` on completion so might also provide a solution here, rather than using `fadeOut` for example:

[jQuery, hide a div without disturbing the rest of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324957/jquery-hide-a-div-without-disturbing-the-rest-of-the-page)

Answer (score 7):

I previously used **`opacity: 0`** before I saw the `visibility: hidden` trick.

But in many cases `opacity: 0` is problematic, because it **lets you interact with the element**, even though you can't see it! (As pointed out by [DeadPassive](https://stackoverflow.com/users/781182/deadpassive).)

Usually that's not what you want.  But perhaps occasionally you might?

Comment: You can't interact with a hidden element, while you can with an element with 0 opacity.

Comment: @feskr If you can think of a situation where it would be advantageous, please do share!

Comment: @joeytwiddle I stumbled upon you answer. I needed to prevent interaction with an element in a certain state, while preserving it's space. I was aware of the fact that visibility: hidden would preserve space, but didn't know it would prevent interaction.