# Create a table without a header in Markdown

Tags: markdown, html-table, multimarkdown

Is it possible to create a table without a header in Markdown?

The HTML would look like this:

```htm
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Key 1</td>
    <td>Value 1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Key 2</td>
    <td>Value 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 162, accepted):

Most Markdown parsers don't support tables without headers. That means the separation line for headers is mandatory.

### Parsers that do *not* support tables without headers

- [multimarkdown](http://fletcher.github.io/peg-multimarkdown/mmd-manual.pdf)
- [Maruku](http://maruku.rubyforge.org): A popular implementation in Ruby
- [byword](http://bywordapp.com/markdown/guide.html): *"All tables must begin with one or more rows of headers"*
- [PHP Markdown Extra](http://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/extra/) *"second line contains a mandatory separator line between the headers and the content"*
- [RDiscount](http://dafoster.net/projects/rdiscount/) *Uses PHP Markdown Extra syntax.*
- [GitHub Flavoured Markdown](https://help.github.com/articles/organizing-information-with-tables/)
- [Parsedown](https://github.com/erusev/parsedown): A parser in PHP (used e.g. in Laravel emails)

### Parsers that *do* support tables without headers.

- [Kramdown](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/): A parser in Ruby
- [Text::MultiMarkdown](http://search.cpan.org/~bobtfish/Text-MultiMarkdown-1.000035/lib/Text/MultiMarkdown.pm): Perl CPAN module.
- [MultiMarkdown](http://fletcherpenney.net/multimarkdown/download/): Windows application.
- [ParseDown Extra](http://parsedown.org/): A parser in PHP.
- [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org/): A document converter for the command line written in Haskell (supports header-less tables via its `simple_tables` and `multiline_tables` extensions)
- [Flexmark](https://github.com/vsch/flexmark-java/wiki): A parser in Java.

### CSS solution

If you're able to change the CSS of the HTML output you can however leverage the `:empty` pseudo class to hide an empty header and make it look like there is no header at all.

Comment: More on CSS solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12023771/hide-empty-cells-in-table

Comment: `:empty` doesn't help because if you only hide the `<th>` it doesn't look right; you have to hide the whole `<tr>` or even the entire `<thead>`.

Answer (score 161):

If you don't mind wasting a line by leaving it empty, consider the following hack (it is a hack, and use this only if you don't like adding any additional plugins).

```
|   |   |
|---|---|
|__Bold Key__| Value1 |
| Normal Key | Value2 |
```

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| **Bold Key** | Value1 |
| Normal Key | Value2 |

To view how the above one could look, copy the above and visit https://stackedit.io/app

It worked with **GitLab**/**GitHub**'s **Markdown** implementations.

Comment: What implementation does that work with? It doesn't work with Perl's Text::MultiMarkdown but I think it might work with some PHP MultiMarkdown implementations.

Comment: It worked with gitlab/github's markdown implementations. I am not sure about perl's Text::MultiMarkdown

Comment: This will create an empty table header and an empty row.

Comment: This actually works great with `pandoc` markdown to pdf.

Comment: Thanks! This works with Laravel 5.8 (multi) markdown as well. No headers are visible - only a line. Looks like a divider, which may can be removed using some CSS in the theme.

Comment: This works well in the "Markdown Viewer" extension in Google Chrome.

Comment: doesn't seem to work in mkdocs

Answer (score 41):

#### Universal Solution

Many of the suggestions unfortunately do not work for all Markdown viewers/editors, for instance, the popular [Markdown Viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/markdown-viewer/ckkdlimhmcjmikdlpkmbgfkaikojcbjk?hl=en) Chrome extension, but they do work with [iA Writer](https://ia.net/writer).

What does seem to work across both of these popular programs (and might work for your particular application) is to use `HTML comment blocks ('<!-- -->')`:

```
| <!-- -->    | <!-- -->    |
|-------------|-------------|
| Foo         | Bar         |
```

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Foo | Bar |

Like some of the earlier suggestions stated, this does add an empty header row in your Markdown viewer/editor. In iA Writer, it's aesthetically small enough that it doesn't get in my way too much.

Comment: This completely defats the point of using Markdown, as when viewed as text-only, the comments will be stripped and the columns won't even align anymore.

Comment: I think @hackel misunderstood. This does not align the columns using fixed widths. Rather, it gives a nice workaround to have valid but empty column headers. It was a great workaround in my situation. The table still rendered as intended/expected; it simply had no header row.

Comment: Nice, yet [this really isn't a **universal** solution](https://babelmark.github.io/?text=%7C+%3C!--+--%3E++++%7C+%3C!--+--%3E++++%7C%0A%7C-------------%7C-------------%7C%0A%7C+Foo+++++++++%7C+Bar+++++++++%7C)

Comment: This will create an empty table header and an empty row.

Comment: @Tony Isn't it better to just leave the header cells empty?

Comment: @UlysseBN Could you point me which Markdown implementations from the link you provided fail to parse this syntax?

Comment: @jsv there 20 failing implementations nowadays, but this may change, just click the link!

Comment: Doesn't work for me (in github issues)

Comment: @theking2 That's odd. I just tried it on github issues and works for me.

Comment: @TonyBarganski I must  have missed a typo. You are right it does work. And actually without the `<!-- -->` in the header line. Leaving empty spaces

Comment: An __Universal Solution__ that doesn't work with PDF...

Comment: @MarcLeBihan I haven't had any issues with PDFs. What are you using to generate your PDF?

Answer (score 20):

I got this working with Bitbucket's Markdown by using a empty link:

```
[]()  | 
------|------
Row 1 | row 2
```

Comment: Will also prompt an empty header line. At least its only half the height as an normal line. Worked for me as Hack in github too

Comment: This hack worked for me when writing documentation in Insomnia. Still creates a header line, but it's a lot shorter than if I put text in there. Thanks!

Comment: Brilliant! I still see a little vertical space with Github Markdown, but it's better than before.

Answer (score 18):

At least for the [GitHub Flavoured Markdown](https://help.github.com/articles/organizing-information-with-tables/), you can *give the illusion* by making all the non‑header row entries **bold** with the regular `__` or `**` formatting:

```
|Regular | text | in header | turns bold |
|-|-|-|-|
| __So__ | __bold__ | __all__ | __table entries__ |
| __and__ | __it looks__ | __like a__ | __"headerless table"__ |
```

| Regular | text | in header | turns bold |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **So** | **bold** | **all** | **table entries** |
| **and** | **it looks** | **like a** | **"headerless table"** |

Comment: I was looking for something that'd work in GFM and this hack is a creative one!

Comment: There's a problem when rendered tables have a different color for header row (e.g. StackExchange).

Comment: By default, the header texts are center aligned, you may want to align them to the left if you don't want the header to standout. In your second line, change it to `|:-|:-|:-|:-|`

Answer (score 10):

Omitting the header above the divider produces a headerless table in at least Perl Text::MultiMarkdown and in FletcherPenney [MultiMarkdown](http://fletcherpenney.net/multimarkdown/download/)

```
|-------------|--------|
|**Name:**    |John Doe|
|**Position:**|CEO     |
```

See [PHP Markdown feature request](https://github.com/michelf/php-markdown/issues/150)

---

Empty headers in PHP [Parsedown](http://parsedown.org/) produce tables with empty headers that are usually invisible (depending on your CSS) and so look like headerless tables.

```
|     |     |
|-----|-----|
|Foo  |37   |
|Bar  |101  |
```

Comment: About the use of Parsedown, actually the header is still here, just check the HTML. If you have a CSS padding on cells you will see the header cells. But I guess that `table th:empty { padding: 0; }` would fix that.

Comment: All of these is now included in [adius' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17543474/7009806).

Answer (score 10):

You may be able to *hide* a heading if you can add the following CSS:

```css
<style>
    th {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

This is a bit heavy-handed and doesn’t distinguish between tables, but it may do for a simple task.

**Update**

HTML output varies between Markdown editors, but if the table includes a `thead` element, you can target the empty header cells more specifically with:

```css
thead th:empty {
    border: thin solid red !important;
    display: none;
}
```

This works if your header row contains no visible content. Spaces between the bars are OK.

Comment: The only CSS trick that works for me for some reason (I'm using VNote with the Markdown-it renderer). None of the solutions given here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12023771/hide-empty-cells-in-table worked.

Answer (score 9):

The following works well for me in GitHub. The first row is no longer bolded as it is not a header:

```
<table align="center">
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><img src="docs/img1.png?raw=true" alt="some text"></td>
        <td align="center">Some other text</td>
        <td align="center">More text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><img src="docs/img2.png?raw=true" alt="some text"></td>
        <td align="center">Some other text 2</td>
        <td align="center">More text 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Check a sample HTML table without a header [here](https://github.com/DWilches/SketchUp).

Comment: This is just what the questioner said they didn't want.

Comment: HTML tables don't seem to work in Bitbucket (https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/html-table-in-readme-does-not-render-as-table/qaq-p/766135) - it displays the HTML itself rather than rendering a table.

Answer (score 4):

```
$ cat foo.md
Key 1 | Value 1
Key 2 | Value 2
```

```htm
$ kramdown foo.md
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Key 1</td>
      <td>Value 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Key 2</td>
      <td>Value 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This seems not to work with https://github.com/chjj/marked .
Is there a reference, in which I can look up if this is even the expected behavior?

Answer (score 2):

what works in GitHub issue editor is

```
&nbsp; |&nbsp;
------ | ---
Foo    | Bar
```

But it does show an empty header

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Foo | Bar |

Comment: As someone with a quasi-Markdown parser that does tables I'm wondering if I should "special case" the first row being non-breaking space cells - and just suppress the header row.

My target (PowerPoint slides) would happily support a headerless table.

Or would this be considered a deviation too far? (I already have a section in the manual for such deviations - so could add this as "some other parsers might not...")

Answer (score 2):

```markdown
<style>
    .headerless th {
        display: none;
    }
</style>

<div class="headerless">

| | |
|---|---|
|Some |table |
| WITHOUT | header |
</div>

|This|is|
|---|---|
|Some |table |
| WITH |header |
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 1):

I use `<span>` in the first column header:

```
 <span> |
---     |    ---
Value   |  Value
Value   |  Value
```

It creates an empty header with border, but with 1/2 the size.

|  |
| --- |
| Value |
| Value |

Answer (score 0):

## Pure CSS solution (working as of 2023-12-19 for all browsers)

1. IF any empty `th`s exist, AND
2. no any `th` elements with content, THEN
3. `display: none;`

```css
/* PURE CSS SOLUTION */

table > thead:has(> tr > th:empty):not(:has(> tr > th:not(:empty))) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<h1>Compiled Markdown</h1>
<div id="markdown-compiled"></div>

<hr>

<h1>Raw Markdown</h1>
<pre><code id="markdown-raw">
<!-- OR USE MARKDOWN INLINE CSS HTML STYLE -->
<style type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
table > thead:has(> tr > th:empty):not(:has(> tr > th:not(:empty))) {
  display: none;
}
</style>
### Empty header

|       |       |
| ----- | ----- |
| Lorem | ipsum |
| dolor | sit   |

### Header with content

|       | not empty |
| ----- | --------- |
| Lorem | ipsum     |
| dolor | sit       |


</code></pre>

<!-- !!! IGNORE THE FOLLOWING !!! -->

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/marked/marked.min.js"></script>

<style>
/* Table styling from https://dev.to/dcodeyt/creating-beautiful-html-tables-with-css-428l */

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 25px 0;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  min-width: 400px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

table thead tr {
    background-color: #009879;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: left;
}

table th,
table td {
    padding: 12px 15px;
}

table tbody tr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

table tbody tr:nth-of-type(even) {
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
}

table tbody tr:last-of-type {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #009879;
}
</style>
<script>
  document.getElementById('markdown-compiled').innerHTML =
      marked.parse(document.getElementById('markdown-raw').innerHTML);
</script>
```