# Hide empty column using CSS and HTML only

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to hide empty column using simple html table?

I've researched this question and have no idea of how to avoid little empty space in every cell of empty column.

I know that there are some jQuery solutions and I can avoid displaying empty column on the backend side, but i need only CSS solution.

DEMO:

```css
td{border: 1px solid red;}
input[type="image"]{width:100px;}
```

```html
<h1>
  Column with one not emty cell.
</h1>
<table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
        <td width="100px">test words</td>
        <td><input type="image" src="http://vectips.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/013.jpg"></td>
        <td><input type="image" src="http://vectips.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/013.jpg"></td>
        <td><input type="image" src="http://vectips.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/013.jpg"></td>
        <td>123</td>
        <td><input type="image" src="http://vectips.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/013.jpg"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="100px">test words</td>
        <td><input type="image" src="http://vectips.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/013.jpg"></td>
        <td><input type="image" src="http://vectips.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/013.jpg"></td>
        <td><input type="image" src="http://vectips.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/013.jpg"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="image" src="http://vectips.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/013.jpg"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<h1>
  Column with all emty cells.
</h1>
<table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
        <td width="100px">test words</td>
        <td><input type="image" src="http://vectips.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/013.jpg"></td>
        <td><input type="image" src="http://vectips.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/013.jpg"></td>
        <td><input type="image" src="http://vectips.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/013.jpg"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="image" src="http://vectips.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/013.jpg"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="100px">test words</td>
        <td><input type="image" src="http://vectips.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/013.jpg"></td>
        <td><input type="image" src="http://vectips.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/013.jpg"></td>
        <td><input type="image" src="http://vectips.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/013.jpg"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="image" src="http://vectips.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/013.jpg"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

There are two cases in the fiddle: when column is completely empty (you can see a 1-2px hole in empty cells) and when column has content in some cells.

**So the task is:**
When column has not empty cell, table must work as it is
When column is completely empty, this column must be fully hidden and musn't perform any space between neighbor columns.

Comment: `td:empty {display: none;}` - have you tried that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide empty cells in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12023771/hide-empty-cells-in-table)

Comment: Can you please duplicate both you html and your css into JSFiddle so everybody could "play" with the existing solution and find a right answer for you. Thanx

Comment: You want to hide the empty cell but still maintain the table structure? Clarify what your intended end result is and provide an example if possible. If you want the cell hidden it will inevitably affect the table structure. Alternatively, you could try `td:empty {visibility: hidden;}`, it shouldn't affect the document flow.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError take a look at the post please.

Comment: @JavaEvgen i have updated the post.

Comment: @Player1 I would advise exploring conditional logic using javascript. The scope of your requirements now exceed the capabilities of CSS and HTML alone. So investigate javscript solutions using `if` conditional statements to check if given cells in given rows are empty and if you are still not coming right after tackling this you can always post a new question, with what you've tried and the SO community will assist where possible within reason. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [CSS :empty Selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_empty.asp).

```
td:empty{
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: It's a bad idea, because rows are going to have different number of columns. Have added the result to question

Comment: Note that IE9-IE11 supports `:empty` but will not repaint/relayout the page if content is added/removed from an :empty selected element.  (per caniuse.com)

Comment: Well, that's what you've asked for.
In case you want to keep the space, you might use `visibility: hidden`, which will keep the space used by the cell. It will hide background and border (and content, which is empty anyway).

Comment: @jp-jee i have added the snippet. Take a look please

Comment: I'm afraid it's not possible (using HTML&CSS only) to style `td`'s depending on others in another `tr`. CSS cannot traverse up in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

```css
td:empty,th:empty {
  display: none;
}
td{width:10%;}
td input{width:100%;}
```

```html
<table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
        <td width="100px">test words</td>
        <td><input type="image" src="http://vectips.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/013.jpg"></td>
        <td><input type="image" src="http://vectips.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/013.jpg"></td>
        <td><input type="image" src="http://vectips.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/013.jpg"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="image" src="http://vectips.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/013.jpg"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="100px">test words</td>
        <td><input type="image" src="http://vectips.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/013.jpg"></td>
        <td><input type="image" src="http://vectips.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/013.jpg"></td>
        <td><input type="image" src="http://vectips.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/013.jpg"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="image" src="http://vectips.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/013.jpg"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I would prefer jp-jee's answer over this, I don't understand the need for an 'empty' class, and it may confuse people looking for the correct answer.

Comment: @Dhaarani take a look at the situation when there is content in one cell of the column. You'll get the result like second demo in my question

Comment: @Player1  img contain td only shown correct. if content there you have to hide

Comment: @Dhaarani i have added fiddle with example

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
td:empty ,th:empty{
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
td{border: 1px solid red;}
input[type="image"]{width:100px;}
.hideemptydiv td:empty{display:none;}
```

```html
<h1>
  Column with one not emty cell.
</h1>
<table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
        <td width="100px">test words</td>
        <td><input type="image" src="http://vectips.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/013.jpg"></td>
        <td><input type="image" src="http://vectips.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/013.jpg"></td>
        <td><input type="image" src="http://vectips.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/013.jpg"></td>
        <td>123</td>
        <td><input type="image" src="http://vectips.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/013.jpg"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="100px">test words</td>
        <td><input type="image" src="http://vectips.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/013.jpg"></td>
        <td><input type="image" src="http://vectips.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/013.jpg"></td>
        <td><input type="image" src="http://vectips.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/013.jpg"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="image" src="http://vectips.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/013.jpg"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<h1>
  Column with all emty cells.
</h1>
<table style="width: 100%" class="hideemptydiv">
    <tr>
        <td width="100px">test words</td>
        <td><input type="image" src="http://vectips.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/013.jpg"></td>
        <td><input type="image" src="http://vectips.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/013.jpg"></td>
        <td><input type="image" src="http://vectips.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/013.jpg"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="image" src="http://vectips.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/013.jpg"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="100px">test words</td>
        <td><input type="image" src="http://vectips.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/013.jpg"></td>
        <td><input type="image" src="http://vectips.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/013.jpg"></td>
        <td><input type="image" src="http://vectips.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/013.jpg"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="image" src="http://vectips.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/013.jpg"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @Player1 now check it.

Comment: it's very close. Failed case: table has both completely empty column and column with one filled cell. In this case structure collapses

Comment: May i use jquery or javascript @Player1

Comment: no. jQuery solution exists, i have already found that but it isn't suitable for me