# Fade Multipie Texts with Buttons Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make a text box or an area on my website, and I have about 9 buttons on the page which I don't want to redirect to other pages and open on the same page and in the same Text Box or Area that I create.

So, if someone clicks on Button 1, then opens Text 1 and its picture(s) with fades in animation, and when clicks on Button 2, Text 1 Box fades out and Text 2 with picture(s) fades in and etc. How can I do this?

I have tried some codes like this

```
$('.one').hide();
$('.two').hide();
$('.three').hide();

$('.btn1').click(function () {
    $('.one').fadeIn();
});

$('.btn2').click(function () {
    $('.one').fadeOut();
    $('.two').fadeIn();

});

$('.btn3').click(function () {
    $('.two').fadeOut();
    $('.three').fadeIn();
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/91jfvqwm/2/)

but when clicking the buttons, the Buttons' position is not fixed and moves with the text animation.

Is there any way to do the same with other codes?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/91jfvqwm/2/

Comment: You can use something like this: https://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery hide element while preserving its space in page layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393632/jquery-hide-element-while-preserving-its-space-in-page-layout)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.one').hide();
$('.two').hide();
$('.three').hide();
$('.btnall').hide();
$('.btn1').click(function () {
    $.when($('.btnall').fadeOut()).done(function(){
    $('.one').fadeIn();
   });
});

$('.btn2').click(function () {
    $.when($('.btnall').fadeOut()).done(function(){
         $('.two').fadeIn();
    });


});

$('.btn3').click(function () {
   $.when($('.btnall').fadeOut()).done(function(){
    $('.three').fadeIn();
   });
});
```

I think this is what you need. 
[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/91jfvqwm/5/)

Comment: Keep on clicking a button

Comment: Please clarify .. what do you want to say.. I didn't get @Tushar

Comment: If flickers animation of the text, keep on clicking `button 1`

Comment: Clicking on buttons still toggles text

Comment: @EOF Not suitable if there are 100 elements

Comment: But I have given the solution as per the requirements. 100 elements is not concerned here

Answer (score 1):

More scalable and dynamic solution:

```
$('button').on('click', function () {
    var targetEl = $(this).data('target');
    $.when($('.' + targetEl).siblings('input').fadeOut()).done(function () {
        $('.' + targetEl).fadeIn();
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<input class="one" value="Text 1">
<input class="two" value="Text 2">
<input class="three" value="Text 3">
<br>
<button data-target="one" class="btn1">Button 1</button>
<br>
<button data-target="two" class="btn2">Button 2</button>
<br>
<button data-target="three" class="btn3">Button 3</button>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/91jfvqwm/8/

Answer (score 0):

You can wait fadeOut to complete before fading in new text field.
for example

```
$('.btn1').click(function () {
    $('.btnall').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $('.one').fadeIn();
    });
});
```