# Scrolling sticky header causing following div to jump when it reaches the top

Tags: jquery, css

I have an issue with a scrolling header, it starts life at the bottom of the browser, once the page scrolls down and the header reaches the top, it fixes.

The issue is when it fixes, the following div will say jump the height of the header to the top.

Here's my jQuery

```
var elementPosition = $('header').offset();

$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() > elementPosition.top){
        $('header').addClass("stick");
    } else {
        $('header').removeClass("stick");
    }
});
```

and here's the css

```
.stick {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the HTML of the header, or even better, a working js fiddle?

Comment: what is the issue? i cant understand.

Comment: hope z-index issue. Its not clear until you provide Fiddle..

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery hide element while preserving its space in page layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393632/jquery-hide-element-while-preserving-its-space-in-page-layout)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem occurs because when making the header fixed, you are removing it from the flow of the page. In doing so, the following content "jumps" up to take its place.

One solution is to add a "ghost" div which is the same height as the header, and hidden by default.

At the point the header reaches the top of the window and you fix it in place, you also unhide the ghost div, which immediately takes its place and prevents the following content from jumping up.

Another solution is to add "margin-top" to the following content, for however tall your header is. This will have the same effect and will prevent the rest of the page content jumping.

Comment: Hi Luke that sounds like a perfects solution, can you show me a quick html / css demo

Comment: Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/w1fs5ho5/ ghost comes in only when header has been fixed. If you then delete the ghost div from the html you'll see the "jumpiness" happening like you have now.

Comment: Thank you, a perfect solution and very smooth unlike some other methods i've tried.

Comment: Not a problem. Happy to help.