# How to preserve space in page layout while reveal/hide elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

### What is happening

[image]

Using `.hide()` and `.fadeIn(200)` is creating this jumpy effect, which I don't want.

### What I want to happen

- When the user hovers over the menu icon,

  - the menu icon to disappear
  - the text "Problems" to fadeIn its place
- When the user moves their mouse away,

  - the text "Problem" to disappear
  - the menu icon to fadeIn its place

So I looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393632/jquery-hide-element-while-preserving-its-space-in-page-layout) which talked about using visibility to show/hide elements. I feel like using visibility might be the key. The only thing is I want the menu icon and "Problems" to replace each other, and w/out the `display` set to `none`, they are stacked on top of each other like so:

[image]

So if I were to use visibility, there would be gaps created by the hidden element.

### My Code

*HTML*

```
<div id="Menu-Header" class="header">
                <button id="Menu-Button" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg button-menu" aria-label="Menu"> 
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <h1>Problems</h1>
                </button>
            </div>
```

*CSS*

```
#Menu-Header h1 {
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: none;
}
```

*jQuery*

```
$('#Menu-Button').on('mouseenter cick', function(){
    $(this).children('.glyphicon-menu-hamburger').hide();
    $(this).children('h1').fadeIn(200);
});

$('#Menu-Button').on('mouseleave', function(){
    $(this).children('h1').hide();
    $(this).children('.glyphicon-menu-hamburger').fadeIn(200);
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/14ongm/utuj88gg/)

Comment: `cick`? Shouldn't it be `click`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a static height to `#Menu-Button` the jumpy effect disappears.  See updated jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/utuj88gg/1/

Comment: @Iarz could you post what exactly you added to the CSS to make the jumpiness disappear? Because I don't see any new code under `#Menu-Button{}`

Comment: @15ongm I just added `height: 69px;`.  I added it separately because I didn't see your initial styling block for it.  My mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Use css height property for the menu icon/problem.